# React+ sending entire state object to another component

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

pretty simple but confused,

i have one parent component with state as 
this is my

this.state = {
      todoName: "",
      todoList: [],
      "isAvail":true,
      "IsArchive":false
    };

and inside my parent component i am calling child component

```
<ChildComponent data= {this.state} />
```

but in childCompoenent inside the render i try to call like

```
const isAvail = this.props.data.isAvail;
const isArchieve = this.props.data.isArchieve;
```

and inside retrun if i call like this am {isAvail} am not getting and am getting error

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {todoName, todoList, isAvail, IsArchive}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

But somehow i need to get full object..How is it possible

Comment: ** Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {todoName, todoList, isAvail, IsArchive}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. **   This type error when you map whole object.You got the whole object and while mapping you  should look for particular element which needs to be mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call like this one

```
render() {
  const {isAvail, isArchieve} = this.props.data;
  return(<div><p>{isAvail}</p></div>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. i forgot. and it works, whats this called in react, i remember something

Comment: yeah. Destructuring

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state= {
      todoName: "passed from parent", todoList: [], "isAvail":true, "IsArchive":false
     }
  }
  render(){
    return <Child data={this.state}/>
 }
}

const Child = (props) => <div>{props.data.todoName}{console.log(props)}</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-germain-6jq66)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know `ContextAPI` & you want to send data without using `props drilling` use`ContextAPI`. In some cases we can use state values in to childcomponents also in using context API.

In your parent component create context

`const ParentState = React.createContext()`

```
 render() {
   <ParentState.Provider value={{ data: this.state }}>
            <Childcomponent/>
   </ParentState.Provider>
}
```

In Child component import Context and use

```
 render() {
   return(
      <ParentState.Consumer>
          {
             parentState => (<div><p>{parentState.data.isAvail}</p></div>)
          }
      </ParentState.Consumer>
   )
}
```

Comment: so when compared with props drilling,what more it have advantages ?i mean contextAPI Vs Props drilling

Comment: if suppose you have multiple childs in parent component. you must to send parent state in to props. In this way we have to reduce & can use wherever your state values what you initialized component under <provider>..</provider>